# An easy problem

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

You are given two number $n$ and $m$ where $n < m$. You perform the following operation until $n \neq m$ or go to an infinite loop.
Operation like

$n = 2n$ and $m = m-n$ (first substract $n$ from $m$ and make $n = 2n$)

if($n > m$) swap($n$, $m$);

Example $1$. $n = 13$  $m = 19$

```
    n = 26  m = 6 swap(n, m) n = 6 m = 26

    n = 12 m = 20

    n = 24 m = 8 swap(n, m) n = 8 m = 24

    n = 16 m = 16 ans will be stop
```

Example $2$. $n = 1$ $m = 4$

```
       n = 2 m = 3

       n = 4 m = 1 swap(n, m) ans will be infinite
```

How can I solve this problem if $n$ and $m < 2^{31} - 1 \log(n)$ complexity

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  not equal

Comment: until $ \neq$ ??? Do you mean while $( n \neq m)$ ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit yes

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that the value $S=n+m$ does not change for either of the operations.

So there are only a finite number of pairs $(n,m)$ ... after a finite number of operations they either hit $(x,x)$ or will  repeat a previous pair.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider $ \pmod{m+n}$.

(Fill in missing gap)

Thus, it stops iff $m+n$ is even and there is a solution to $2^k n \equiv \frac{ m+n}{2} \pmod{m+n}$.